# Repaint method update is too slow

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, repaint

We are currently developing a connect four game as university project and I have to handle the GUI.

To solve this I have a custom component for each stone called "GameStone":

```
public class GameStone extends Component
{

private final int row;
private Color stoneColor;

public GameStone(int row, MouseListener mouse){
    this.row = row;
    this.addMouseListener(mouse);
    this.stoneColor = Color.WHITE;
}

public int getRow(){
    return row;
}

public void setColor(Color color){
    this.stoneColor = color;

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g); 

     //fills the stones with the set color
    g.setColor(stoneColor);       
    g.fillOval(5, 5, 25, 25);

    // sets the border of the playstones
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(5,5 , 25, 25);


}
}
```

These components will be added in a JPanel with a gridlayout:

```
 graphicField = new GameStone[7][6];
    stoneListener = new GameStoneListener(gamecontrol);

    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(6, 7, 10, 10);

    playArea.setLayout(grid);
    for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            graphicField[j][i] = new GameStone(j, MouseListener);
            playArea.add(graphicField[j][i]);
        }

    }
```

To catch all status changes I use a Listener on the 2d array which is used on the playfield and then will inform my view. In the view I will use repaint to show the changes.

However when I play against the KI the playfield is only painted once the KI is done. Also the problem doesn't seem to exist when I call it with the "paint"-method (which I shouldn't use, it was just to see if the paint call works)

I also only refresh my JPanel instead of my JFrame and also tried to use JComponent instead of Component, all to no avail.

What I also have to say that the AI is a CPU-time hogging one. Could it be that the event can't be executed because its busy with the AI?

I know that the "Thread.sleep" will shut down the EDT so its not recommended. What can I do to make two refreshes, once the user clicked and once the AI is done?

Currently I call repaint() on "playArea" which I think is correct. I'm willing to learn though;)

Comment: `What I also have to say that the AI is a CPU-time hogging one` - somewhere in your code you have probably created an infinite loop that invokes repaint(), or if you are using a Timer to schedule the painting then the timer interval is too small.

Comment: @camickr weird thing is that the second time I call repaint() under the exact same conditions it works.

Basically I let the user make his play, then my listener on the 2d array playfield is activated which causes me to repaint

After that the computer does his play and uses the same method to set the stone (which also causes me to repaint)

However only the second repaint() seems to do anything

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix swing and awt. Change your class to extend JComponent

```
 public class GameStone extends JComponent
```

And override `paintComponent()` method instead of `paint()`

Comment: I used:
@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(stoneColor);       
        g.fillOval(5, 5, 25, 25);
        
        // sets the border of the playstones
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(5,5 , 25, 25);
       
    }

I don't need to implement the paint method anymore right?
As far as I have found out that method is also called by repaint(), is that correct?

I also don't need to overwrite anything in my JPanel "playArea" right? So far the problem still persists.

Comment: "What I also have to say that the AI is a CPU-time hogging one. Could it be that the event can't be executed because its busy with the AI?" - seems simple to test, replace the AI with a dumb one that does not hog the CPU and see if that makes a difference. I'm guessing yes. Is the AI running on its own thread?